# Vector addition in a Lagrangian problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, velocity, textbook-erratum

I am currently looking at the first question in [this](http://www.dzre.com/alex/P441/lectures/lec_18.pdf) set of Lagrangian problems. I feel a little silly having to ask this, but I am having difficulty seeing why the kinetic energy of the box, $T_m$ is given by:

$$T_m=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}_1^2+\dot{x}_2^2+2\dot{x}_1\dot{x}_1\cos({\theta}))$$

[image: The figure from the problem sheet]

I am (probably naively) trying to think of this problem in regular xy-coordinates, in which case the resulting velocity vector is given by:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \dot{x}_1 + \dot{x_2}\cos(\theta) \\
    -\dot{x_2}\sin(\theta) \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I am calculating the square of this vector as:

$$\vec{v}^2=v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2$$

giving:

$$\vec{v}^2=(\dot{x_1}+\dot{x_2}\cos(\theta))^2+(-\dot{x_2}\sin(\theta))^2=\dot{x_1}^2+\dot{x_2}^2+2\dot{x_2}\dot{x_1}\cos(\theta)$$

which is wrong. I think my problem is either in my use of xy-coordinates in a problem with non-orthogonal axes, or I have just used the incorrect method in squaring the velocity vector.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a typo in the notes (the last $\dot{x_1}$ should be $\dot{x_2}$).  Equation 7 in the notes seems to confirm this.

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit I think you're right. It seems odd to have split the $\dot{x_1}$ in the last term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, this is a typo in the notes.

Answer (score 1):

The addition law for vectors is the law of cosines,
$$
|\vec a + \vec b|^2 = |\vec a|^2 + |\vec b|^2 + 2\vec a\cdot\vec b.
$$
As you have noticed, your vectors are
$$
\vec a = \begin{bmatrix}\dot x_1\\0\end{bmatrix},~~~~\vec b=\begin{bmatrix}\dot x_2\cos\theta\\-\dot x_2 \sin\theta\end{bmatrix},
$$
from which one can read straight off,
$$
|\vec a + \vec b|^2 = \dot x_1^2 + \dot x_2^2 + 2\dot x_1\dot x_2\cos\theta.
$$